# How to build docker image for laravel 10 using buildpack

Tags: laravel, docker, containers, buildpack, paketo

I'm trying to create an app image for my laravel 10 app without writing a docker file with buildpack, I've reading the official docs using of paketo and discovered the build code

```
pack build my-app --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/php \
  --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:full
```

The problem is, laravel 10 is using node js too. is there's realy a way to build a laravel 10 app image using buildpack?

Answer (score 1):

The Paketo PHP buildpack doesn't include Node by default but you can provide the Paketo `node-engine` buildpack to the build. Due to the way buildpacks work, we need another buildpack to "require" Node, so you'd also likely have to add the `build-plan` buildpack to require Node.

Your build command would look like:

```
pack build my-app --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/php \
  --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/node-engine \
  --buildpack paketo-community/build-plan \
  --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:full
```

Then, you'd need to add a "plan.toml" file to your app to require Node as mentioned above. The `requires.metadata` section changes depending on whether you need Node during the build (`build = true`) or at run-time (`launch = true`):

```
[[requires]]
  name = "node"
  version = "<version constraint>"
[requires.metadata]
  launch = true
```

If this is a common use case, we could think about potentially adding first-class support for Node to the PHP buildpack in the future. Feel free to open an issue on GitHub at https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/php to discuss this further.